# RingCentral Salesforce: How do I login to app using RingCentral sandbox user details

Tags: salesforce, ringcentral

I need login into RingCentral Salesforce app using sandbox user details, is there any way to do that.

When I click to 'Sign In' button it opens `service.ringcentral.com/login/oauth.html?session=....` How do I change to `service.devtest.ringcentral.com...`?

I want to test RingCentral APIs from Apex trigger on tasks which is being created through RingCentral Salesforce app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am from the RingCentral product team. Currently you cannot use your sandbox user details to login into RingCentral for Salesforce integration. We are looking to open up access to our Salesforce integration using sandbox credentials in the future. For now you can access our SF integration by signing up for our [Office Premium or Enterprise trial](https://www.ringcentral.com/office/plansandpricing.html).